# LEDs in the audio path - linearity?

Tags: led, audio, multiplexer, frequency-modulation

I'm repairing an ancient stereo multiplex decoder which has diodes in the signal path for mono/stereo switching.

For headroom reasons, I need plenty of Vf on these diodes, which are pulled up by a DC signal generated from the pilot tone. So I am wondering whether there is any linearity reason why I couldn't use a suitable LED. That would also give me some nice indicator lighting at the same time of course.

Comment: Could you draw the circuit. Are the diodes part of a balanced detector?

Comment: @JImDearden There is a balanced demodulator but these particular diodes aren't part of it. They are in series with the demodulator output and therefore in series with the audio.

Comment: Yes, show us the circuit. Why do you think "plenty of Vf" will increase rather than decrease audio headroom?

Comment: @DaveTweed Because I put some low Vf signal diodes and I got 2HD. THe ciruit is a little too much to put here in toto and it wouldn't make a lot of sense as an extract. The question is very simplle. Is an LED linear enough in series with audio in the same way that say a 1N4148 is?

Comment: diodes aren't linear devices anyway. The basic difference between the LED and 1n4148 types is down to turn on voltage, noise, speed etc. but an LED can be used as a diode.

Comment: @JImDearden So is an LED which is forward-biased enough beyond the point of conduction sufficiently linear to use in series with audio in the same way that a 1N4148 is? for example a 1N4148 used in a balanced demodulator?

Comment: Show the circuit!  It doesn't make sense that you need higher forward drop on the mux diodes for some reason.  The explanation you give for that doesn't make sense.  *It is difficult to tell what is being asked here*, especially since you've been back here and are still refusing to provide a schematic.  All that's left to do is close this question.

Comment: I disagree. The question is perfectly simple. Is an LED comparable in linearity to a small-signal diode like 1N4148 when used in series with audio. The actual circuit is irrelevant to the question. There are hundreds of FM MPX circuits that use small signal diodes in series with the audio in the demodulator.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're refusing to provide the circuit in question, this can only be a generic answer.

When diodes are used for signal switching, there are two considerations with regard to the magnitude of the signal relative to the DC control signal.

- In the blocking state, the reverse bias voltage must be greater than the peak signal voltage in order to prevent signal leakage. Also, a high bias voltage reduces the parasitic capacitance through the diode.
- In the on state, the forward DC control current through diode must be greater than the peak AC signal current, and it must be enough larger so that the current doesn't approach the "knee" of the diode curve too closely, introducing distortion.

In the latter case, a large value of V<sub>F</sub> for the diode reduces the signal margin relative to the control signal.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's clear I'm asking for a generic answer.

Comment: My sentiments exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how linear is "linear enough", and how you bias the LEDs, but generally, yes you could put an LED in series with an audio signal without causing horrible distortion. Certainly if a 1N4148 is acceptable, so too could be an LED.

The reason is this: an ideal diode is horribly non-linear under all conditions, with current and voltage having an exponential relationship. However for real diodes, at some point past \$V_f\$, the current allowed by the LED becomes dominated by the internal resistance of the LED. This resistance is much more linear.

Check out this, from [LTL-307EE](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/LTL-307EE.pdf), with the linear-ish region highlighted:

[image: graph of current vs voltage]